# Force dimensionality with shp2pgsql

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql

After invoking:

`shp2pgsql -W "latin1" theshape.shp > thesql.sql`

My console responds with:

```
Shapefile type: PolygonZ
Postgis type: MULTIPOLYGON[2]
```

Note the shapefile type is `PolygonZ`. The result is, I have to manually edit the `thesql.sql` file and wrap the geometry column in [`ST_Force_2D()`](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Force_2D.html) before executing the SQL, otherwise, Postgres complains I'm trying to import a 3D shape into a 2D column.

How can I force dimensionality to 2 with `shp2pgsql`?
Alternatively, can I force it in QGIS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
shp2pgsql -t 2D theshape.shp > thesql.sql
```

For a full list of options you can run

```
shp2pgsql --help
```

Edit:

You'll probably also want to define the projection and throw in a spatial index.  You can do so with

```
shp2pgsql -t 2D -s 4326 -I theshape.shp > thesql.sql
```

Just replace 4326 with the EPSG code of your coordinate reference system.

Comment: `man shp2pgsql` makes no mention of this parameter, whereas `shp2pgsql --help` does. Thanks. The output from the console is still PolygonZ... which is confusing -- nevertheless, Postgres doesn't complain. Cheers.

Comment: Nevermind, the PolygonZ indicates the Shapefile type... which makes sense. ;)