# MULTIPOLYGONM vs MULTIPOLYGON with shp2pgsql

Tags: postgis, shapefile, shp2pgsql

I have already seen [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57932/force-dimensionality-with-shp2pgsql)

I am running the following:

```
shp2pgsql -I -s 3401 -t 2D theShapeFile.shp table_name > file_name.sql
```

And the response I see is:

```
Shapefile type: PolygonM
Postgis type: MULTIPOLYGONM[2]
```

My database does not support MULTIPOLYGONM (and I cannot upgrade).

**How can I force the output to be MULTIPOLYGON instead of MULTIPOLYGONM ?**

Comment: I don't think you can directly. Is your data actually MultiPolygonM or is it just declared that way. Because if the latter, you can always do a regex replace or similar on file_name.sql.

Comment: Use ogr2ogr for conversion and cast geometrytype into polygon with -nlt MULTIPOLYGON.

Comment: @JohnBarça: I do not really know how to tell if the data is MultiPolygonM or not.  But based on your suggestion I just edited file_name.sql and removed the M, and then running that SQL worked.  Thank you.  If you convert your comment into an  answer, I will mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the solution was to edit the resulting .sql file and remove the letter M so that the type was MULTIPOLYGON.  Then I was able to import the .sql file into PostgreSQL.

I do not know if there is any difference in the resulting shapes in PostgreSQL, but non were reported by users.